# How do I force Installshield 2012 to perform a major upgrade?

Tags: visual-studio, upgrade, installshield, major-upgrade

My installer is performing a minor upgrade when going from 1.7.211 to 1.7.212, but I want it to always perform a major upgrade. A new installer should always overwrite everything that the previous installer installed, without exception. Is there a way to modify the installshield project to accomplish this?

Comment: Which project type? MSI or non-MSI? Basic or InstallScript?

Comment: msi type I guess. (Both .exe and .msi are generated, and the .exe extracts an msi as part of the installation process), not sure if it's basic or installscript.  I basically never, ever want to do a minor update. I want it to consider any change in the version number to constitute a major update.

Answer (score 1):

For MSI projects, go to the 'upgrades' area (under 'Media'). Under 'upgrade windows installer setup' create a new Major Upgrade item. For that item, select 'Within a specific range of version' and set the maximum version to be a version number which is greater than the current one (e.g. 1.8 in your case).

This way, when Windows Installer detects it should run in upgrade mode, it will see that the currently installed version (1.7.11) applies to the major upgrade rule, and will proceed with performing a major upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using a basic MSI or InstallScript MSI project type. For every release, you must take the necessary steps the enact a major upgrade (and, to be precise, this is an [MSI rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786(v=vs.85).aspx), not an InstallShield rule).

In your InstallShield project, author a Major Upgrade in the Upgrades view. You need to say "any previous version" when setting that up.

Then, for every release, you need to increment the version number (one of the first three digits, MSI ignores the fourth) and the product code GUID.

I disagree with your statement of "A new installer should always overwrite everything that the previous installer installed, without exception." There are many deployment models when only updating files that have changed between releases is a top priority. If that model works for you currently, great. Just be open to the possibility of minor and patch upgrades and what those look like in terms of release planning.

Comment: Why do I have to touch the product code GUID? Shouldn't "any previous version" take care of that? Is there a way to tie that directly to the version number, so it's all automatic when a new build is created?

Comment: If you want a major upgrade, you have to roll product code GUID. That's just part of how MSI works. You don't want to roll product GUID with every build, either. Every RELEASE is OK. I want to reiterate that auto-forcing a major upgrade with every release is something to reconsider.